# Find Longest Path on DAG with Networkx in Python

Tags: python, networkx, directed-graph, longest-path

I have a very large DAG of strings (~200k). I would like to find the longest path that exists in this graph. The below code is how I've set up the graph (from the list of strings `new_list`).

```
#create new empty graph
g = nx.DiGraph()

#add all words to graph
for word in new_list:
    g.add_node(word)

#fill graph with valid word chains
for word in g.nodes():
    for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
        new_word = alphagramatize(word+c) #add char c to word in alphagram order
        if(binary_search(new_list, new_word) != -1):
            g.add_edge(word, new_word)
```

I have attempted the naive approach of checking the path distance from every node to every other node... this is clearly impractical and will not terminate.

I have also attempted to rework the `longest_path()` code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985202/networkx-efficiently-find-absolute-longest-path-in-digraph) thread, to no avail.

I have read much on what I could understand about performing a topological sort and ordering of the graph, but am having trouble implementing this. Networkx provides a function `topological_sort(g)`, so that work is done for me. However, how do I proceed from here now that I have a topo_sorted graph?

Comment: What doesn't work with the code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985202/networkx-efficiently-find-absolute-longest-path-in-digraph ?

Comment: @Aric It seems only to output a single node in my graph with a distance. I am searching for the entire path (all nodes in the longest path). I notice yours adds paths (`G.add_path()`) rather than adding edges like mine (`G.add_edge()`). Should I rework my code to generate paths rather than edges?

Comment: No adding edges is fine.  I updated that answer with (hopefully) a corrected version :-).  That one was profoundly wrong except for the special case I tested it on...

Comment: @Aric Your updated code works wonders! Thank you sir!