# Find longest path on DAG from source node

Tags: python, graph-algorithm, networkx

I am trying to find the longest path of a DAG from vertex 0. After searching on Stackoverflow, I understand that I can invert the weighting of the edges and use the Bellman Ford algorithm to find the longest path. However, I don't fully understand how this works.

My graph however has no weighting (all are equal), I assume I should just set to -1?

I am using networkx and python to solve this. Here is my Bellman code:

```
def Bellman(G):
    pred, dist = nx.bellman_ford(G, 0, weight='-1')
    print(dist)
```

No matter what weight I set, I still get the lowest distance for every node from 0. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: SO answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985202/networkx-efficiently-find-absolute-longest-path-in-digraph

Comment: @Aric that is for absolute in a graph, I'm looking from a particular source node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [networkx documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.bellman_ford.html?highlight=bellman_ford), the weight parameter to `bellamn_ford` is the key of an edge attribute which contains the weight. I guess by setting it to the non-existing edge attribute `'-1'`, it does not consider any weights. What you will have to do to make this work is creating an edge attribute that is set to `-1` for all edges:

```
for n in G:
  for nbr in G[n]:
    G[n][nbr]['myWeight'] = -1
```

and then call Bellman-Ford using this attribute as weights:

```
pred, dist = nx.bellman_ford(G, 0, weight='myWeight')
```

Note that instead of using a "custom" attribute like `'myWeight'`, you could also set the default attribute `'weight'` to -1 and then call Bellman-Ford without having to explicitly specify the weight-Parameter.

Comment: Just a clarification: either to do G[n][nbr]['weight'] instead of 'myWeight'  so that that you can call nx.bellman_ford(G,0) without specifying the weight parameter as it is 'weight' by default. Or you have to call as follows: nx.bellman_ford(G,0,weight='myWeight'])

Comment: @AbdallahSobehy thank's for pointing this out. I've included this clarification into the answer.

Comment: @matz and I have to invert the result again to get the actual lengths to each node yes?

Comment: @ForeverLearning yes -- the `dist` returned by the `bellman_ford` contains the weights summed up along the path, which will be negative in this case.